# YouTube Embed, URL From Database Query

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to display a youtube embed using the URL that the user put on their profile.

It works correctly if the URL in the database is http://youtube.com/embed/URL

I'd like users to be able to just input a regular URL (http://youtube.com/URL because I want it to be easy for them.

Is there a way to get around this?

Thanks a lot for any help, I'm quite new at this!

Comment: So it shows up if `src='URL'` but not if `src='".$row['videourl']."'`?

Comment: Ok so I just figured out that it's not showing up because /embed is not in the url in the database. But since I want users to just be able to put in a regular YouTube URL, I'd like to find a workaround.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a workaround to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try copying and pasting this, and see if it works:

```
echo '<br>';
echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="' . stripslashes($row['videourl']) . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

If it's not showing up based on the fact that the person entering the URL doesn't place `embed` in their link, then what I would recommend is just having the person enter the ID of the video, and you create the rest of the URL.

For example, if the URL to the video a user wants to post is `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0TL5CSPFzTU` then they would just enter `0TL5CSPFzTU` and you would output your code as such:

```
echo '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . stripslashes($row['videourl']) . '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
```

You'd have to put something in place that stops them from entering the full URL, or anything more than the ID, but there are plenty of tutorials out there for accomplishing that.

Comment: Thank you! It definitely works. I just need to make it clear to users to only copy that last part! Thanks again. I'd upvote you if I had the "reputation".

Comment: You're welcome, Patrick. You can still mark it as your selected answer. That's worth more points. :) Also, look into regex's because you can use those to strip out any additional information someone posts in the field.